# The println statement is working inside a block {} or inside a function but it is not working inside the class without function or block?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
public class Main
{
    System.out.println("Error in this line"); //line 1
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Executed succesfully"); //line 2
    }
}
```

Here the third line shows an error

```
illegal start of type
```

What does it mean?

Comment: It is not in a code block.

Comment: How does code block works?

Comment: As you mention in your title a code block is surrounded by {}. I suggest following a few Java tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any executable code should be inside a block. Block can be method, constructor, static block or initializer block.

**Sample Code:**

```
public class Main {

  // Initializer block
  {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }

  // Static block
  static {
    System.out.println("dd");
  }

  // Constructor
  public Main() {
    System.out.println("Executed succesfully");
  }

  // Method
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Executed succesfully");
  }

  public static String testMethod() {
    System.out.println("Executed succesfully");
    return "test";
  }

}
```